# Losing reputation after suggested edit which are not mine

Tags: discussion, support

I've got a notification telling me that I've got an *edit suggested* by the author of a question (asked a month ago) on my answer and it was rejected by 3 persons.

I've search the help section but could not found out why I lost 15 reputation points.

Can someone tell me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lost 15 reputation points because [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860923/how-to-switch-two-letters-in-a-string/24861050#24861050) was *unaccepted* yesterday by the OP of the question. You may check this on the [reputation tab of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3633399/xlander?tab=reputation).

Reputation drop had nothing to do with the edit.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. Well it's just weird. He liked the answer and unaccepted it. lol

Answer (score 2):

You most likely lost 15 points because someone unaccepted an answer you made on the same day you made it. If an event is cancelled on the same day it was made (Ex. answer accepted then unaccepted), it doesn't show on the rep log. But if you are active enough, you may see yourself gain and lose reputation.

So probably the suggested edit didn't actually do anything.

Comment: Thanks you, it was already in my log.